# Dropbox showing error, when asking for access token

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I I am working on a PHP application in which I need to integrate Dropbox. I am doing this in file1.php file. Following is the code:

```
require_once ("../dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php");
    use \Dropbox as dbx;
    $appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("../dropbox-config.json");
    $csrfTokenStore = new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
    $webAuth = new dbx\WebAuth($appInfo, "MyApp", "https://example.net/app2/OAuthRedirectURI.php", $csrfTokenStore);
    $authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."|".session_id());
```

Since redirect uri cannot be dynamic, I have specified redirect uri to `https://example.net/app2/RedirectURI.php`.

In `$webAuth->start()` method, I have sent full path of file1.php and session id. This is because, I need to redirect to file1.php from RedirectURI.php file.

Following is the code of RedirectURI.php:

```
$stateArray = explode("|", $_GET['state']);
    session_id($stateArray[2]);
    session_start();
    $_GET['state'] = $stateArray[0];
    $_SESSION['DBX_AUTH_CODE_GET'] = $_GET;
    header("location:".$stateArray[1]);
```

In RedirectURI.php, I am getting auth code and parameters that I have sent, separated by pipe symbol. After creating session, I put $_GET array in session and redirected to file1.php.

In file1.php, following is the code to get access token:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['DBX_AUTH_CODE_GET'])){
$x = $_SESSION['DBX_AUTH_CODE_GET'];
        list($accessToken, $userId, $urlState) = $webAuth->finish($x);
        echo "access token: " . $accessToken;
    }
```

But it is showing error:

```
PHP fatal error in line 242 of file /var/www/html/example/public_html/app2/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/WebAuth.php.
Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\WebAuthException_Csrf' with message 'Expected '6r9eW-MB82JxkJU9AE7u9g==', got 'KkgZk4491XEPhsn_14EObw=='.' in 
/var/www/html/example/public_html/app2/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/WebAuth.php:242nStack trace:n#0 /var/www/html/example/public_html/app2/pm/file1.php(40): 
Dropbox\WebAuth->finish(Array)n#1 {main}n thrown
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: The error is being raised since you don't catch the `WebAuthException` which is being thrown if the given 'state' parameter doesn't contain the CSRF token from the user's session. Try to debug the code by printing the token in each and every step, does it change or stay the same?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do I need to create CSRF token myself or Dropbox sdk does that?

Comment: $csrfTokenStore = new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');

What does this code do?

Comment: Try to add `session_start()` at the top of the first block of code, for instance, above: `require_once ("../dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php");`

Comment: I already have session_start() on top of file. Can you please tell what below code does:

$csrfTokenStore = new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');

Comment: Please consider following my first advice and try to debug the token and check where is it being changed. It defines an entry in an array (http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.ArrayEntryStore.html)